# Can react native build to iPad OS?

Tags: ios, react-native, ipados

Can react native build to iPad OS ?
till now we have react native to build iOS apps and android apps. Apple is separating iPad OS from iOS, do you think react Native still be able to solve the cross platform problem....?

iPad OS is supposed to be out by next sept/ oct apple event

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should still be possible. "iPad OS" is basically just a different name. The technology is still the same.

Comment: yes, but my question is whether React Native framework creating apps for iPad also...

Comment: Yes, React Native can also build apps for iPad, including for iPadOS

Answer (score 1):

Yes. iPadOS is built on the same foundation as iOS, but since Apple has added several features specific to the iPad, it has decided to give it its own name: "iPadOS".

So if your app was built and released on older iOS versions such as iOS 12, users with iPhone or iPad on iOS 13 will still be able to install your app.

Comment: yes, but my question is whether React Native framework creating apps for iPad also...

Comment: @Sree there's no poblem creating iPad apps. It will soon support all iPadOS features as well.